# compile with the libc library

Tags: gcc, libc

I used stricmp() in my code [described here](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.1/neutrino/lib_ref/s/stricmp.html)

It gives a compile error `undefined reference to`stricmp'`.

How to compile with libc library with -c option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stricmp()` is a QNX 4 function. The POSIX equivalent is `strcasecmp()`.